# Add column to Membership Details report

Tags: reports

It seems to me that this should be easy - but I cannot figure out how to do this. I would like to create a Membership Detail report and for those members who are of type Individual, I would like to show their Employer. What is an easy way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On current versions of civicrm as per demo at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/22?reset=1 you can click on Column tab and tick 'Organization Name' (which is the organisation the person is an employee of).

Organization Name was added as of CiviCRM 4.6.9 - see [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17115).

Comment: The usual caveat applies.  This depends on the version they have.  In older version organization isn't available.  (Also on new installs the membership report is 22 but in version installed awhile ago it may not be)

Comment: We are running CiviCRM 4.6.8. Organization name is not an option should under Columns and the report is 22.

Comment: updated my answer to clarify re versions

Comment: @GRoston - You're in luck.  Someone else had the same need not too long ago.  I just updated Pete's answer above to indicate that your problem was solved with CiviCRM 4.6.9 - so upgrade to the latest 4.6 (currently 4.6.11) and you're all set!